# CATextLayer text font going out on increasing text size

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

[image]

The above picture show a red color `CATextLayer` frame.

When I Increase text font size, text goes out of frames.

I am using pinch gesture to increase the font size. I want to get the size of the text in the `CATextLayer` so that I can put some logic to stop increasing the font size if the text frame goes out the layer frame.

How can I do this ?

Comment: Please don't use all caps in your posts, this is aggressive for readers. Thanks. :)

Comment: @richard-g Please do not add "Thanks" to posts. On the contrary, we are supposed to *remove* the useless fluff... Also, block quotes are for code. Don't overuse them.

Answer (score 0):

Could you post your code?

Maybe this will help you also: a `CATextLayer` is like a lightweight, layer-level version of a `UILabel`. If the width of the layer is insufficient to display the entire string, you can get truncation behaviour with the `truncationMode` property. If the `wrapped` property is set to true, the string will wrap. The string property can be an `NSAttributedString`.

Comment: same question, more detailed
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47772963/catextlayer-number-of-lines