# CATextLayer number of lines?

Tags: objective-c, calayer, catextlayer

My CATextlayer support only 1 line
otherwise the text is cut.

trying to set text content like UILabel Behaviour... is it possible?

1. set "number of lines"
2. adjust text size by **static** CATextLayer frame

[image]

```
CATextLayer *text_layer= [[CATextLayer alloc] init];
[text_layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor].CGColor];
[text_layer setBackgroundColor:[UIColor blueColor].CGColor];
[text_layer setForegroundColor:layers.textColor.CGColor];
[text_layer setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
[text_layer setBorderColor:layers.borderColor.CGColor];
[text_layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,50)]; //note: frame must be static
[text_layer setString:@"thank you for your respond"];
 text_layer.wrapped = YES;
[text_layer setAlignmentMode:kCAAlignmentCenter];
```

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line right here, `[text_layer setFrame:CGRectMake(0,0,200,50)];`. I don't think a CATextLayer would lay itself out to accommodate multiple lines. It will only re-draw the text to wrap within the layer's bounds. Try adjusting your text layer's frame based on the text being set. You can create a `UILabel` instance, to calculate the frame for having multiline text with word wrapping and set it to your `CATextLayer` instance.

Here's a `UILabel` category to calculate text size for multiline text with word wrapping:

```
@interface UILabel (Height)

- (CGSize)sizeForWrappedText;

@end

@implementation UILabel (Height)

- (CGSize)sizeForWrappedText {
    UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, self.bounds.size.width, CGFLOAT_MAX)];
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    label.font = self.font;
    label.text = self.text;
    [label sizeToFit];
    return label.frame.size;
}

@end
```

Create a `UILabel` instance, and use the `sizeForWrappedText` to get the size. Something like this:

```
// Make sure the someFrame here has the preferred width you want for your text_layer instance.
UILabel *label = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:someFrame];
[label setText:@"My awesome text!"];

CGRect frame = text_layer.frame;
frame.size = [label sizeForWrappedText];
[text_layer setFrame:frame];
```

Comment: Hi Parnay, 
my text layer's *frame must be static* all time.
I need to find how to break lines & resize the text by the frame size. (like UILabel Behaviour... is it possible?)

Comment: Yeah, it depends. If your label's frame needs to be static, then at some point the string would be truncated if the size of the text exceeds the size of your label. Try setting truncationMode to kCATruncationNone. This way, the text won't truncate and would wrap within the text layer's bounds. But if the size exceeds, it would simply clip the excessive text. Even a UILabel would truncate text at some point if you set a fixed frame to it.